# How good is GoogleApp Engine to build a web application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications

After quite a bit of research, and many of the blogs/posts/tutorials is out of date. 
I can not figure out if Google App engine is good enough to build a webapp nowadays. Consider only Java as a language.
Any suggestion?

Comment: as good as any. this question is not constructive according to FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

There are [more than hundred thousands apps](http://www.bitcurrent.com/how-many-google-app-engine-apps-are-there/) in Google App Engine.. So Yes, I guess its stable enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

GAE is definitely production-ready, and has been for a long time. But the choice whether it suits your needs depends on, well, your needs. As a full and inflexible stack, by committing to GAE you are limiting yourself to the functionality provided by it. You do get a whole lot in return.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blogpost from Udacity. They developed a web development course around google app engine:

http://googleappengine.blogspot.nl/2012/10/teaching-thousands-of-students-to.html

And this hangout: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/9826022/